# $Z_5$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The question asks me if $Z_5$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$.

What I was thinking of doing is writing down all the elements of $S_4$ and then again finding the subgroups generated by every element. But that is just very long. I assume there should be a proper way to check this. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: use Lagrange.

Comment: What do you know about the order of an element of $S_4$?

Comment: By Lagrange, the order of an element of $S_4$ must divide 24, so the possible orders are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, and 24.

Comment: Oh I see, so 5 is not a  possible size of the subgroup generated by $S_4$. So, it cannot be isomorphic to $Z_5$.

Comment: @lulu just wondering, what if it was $Z_6$ instead of $Z_5$?

Comment: See [the Landau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not a subgroup of $S_4$, but you need to know about the structure of elements in $S_4$ to conclude this easily.

Comment: Every permutation breaks up into cycles, so to get an element of order $6$ you'd need a partition of the four elements with LCM $=6$.  No such exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First, we know $|S_4|=4!=24,$ and $|\Bbb{Z}_5|=5$. Then it is clear that $5$ does not divide $24,$ and by Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup of $S_4$ must divide $24.$ So no such subgroup can exist.